# Could people ease up please while approving edits another user makes to his own question/answer?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868731/while-loop-unexpected-character-to-int-conversion/22868956#22868956) within a few minutes of it being posted, I had to fight to be allowed to fine-tune my answer: review queue history (reviewer names edited out as this is not personal):

XXX.XXX reviewed this 10 mins ago: Reject
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
XXX.XXX reviewed this 11 mins ago: Reject
This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
XXX.XXX reviewed this 11 mins ago: Reject
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

The edit history, over a period of maybe 5 minutes, went about as follows: notice indentation missing - add it; notice user might not understand why a positive number can turn into a negative one - add a reference to why this could happen; notice it would be nice to add sample output - add it.

The entire reference to the IEEE representation of integers, which is potentially very relevant for a beginner who has never seen it, was reverted by a reviewer. I cannot see how improving on your layout isn't beneficial to SO, or adding additional info for clarification. Certainly none of my changes was 'incorrect'.

I am familiar with the rule in place to prevent insubstantial edits. To the best of my knowledge it is supposed to prevent people from going on editing sprees to boost their reputation from useless edits; in the worst case of gravedigger-old questions that get prompted back to the front page. This hardly applies to improving a question with a few minutes of being posted - all the more with editor == original author. I also wasn't front-running to competitively get an answer on the page first: mine was second, just - in my eyes - substantially improved upon the first answer.

I don't have any suggestion to prevent it from happening, but I would humbly ask people to please ease up in their review process and let others actually post a respectful answer as they see fit.

Comment: You are talking about suggested edits to the *question* correct?

Comment: No, those to improve my own answer (obviously, the same would apply if it would have been a question I later notice I can improve upon).

Comment: Then you weren't logged in to Stack Overflow with the right account. You should *never* have to get approval for edits to your own answer.

Comment: All I know is that some of my changes were undone/rejected; it were changes to my own answer (to the question linked above); and I found what I pasted in as the second paragraph of this question in my inbox.

Comment: If there was a problem with "IEEE representation of integers", that might have been a valid technical concern; see the comment I just posted on [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22868956/827263).

Comment: @Pëkka: I was (and am) logged into SO with the only account I have here.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That is a good comment (that I upvoted), but I don't think it is a good idea to let a reviewer simply delete a wrong, or possibly not quite right, statement from your answer (but from the feedback above, it seems that what happened shouldn't have happened, and might be more of a bug report).

Comment: @gnometorule there are only 1 edit to that post, yours from 6 minutes after it was posted.  And your account only has 1 edit today in the history (which was the one to that post) and no record of any suggested edits since December.  If you tried to edit your own post, you weren't logged in, or were logged in with a different account.  In that case any edit rejections would have been justified.

Comment: Are you talking about this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4502805 ? That wasn't suggested by you.

Comment: Even without the review mechanism, anyone with sufficiently high rep can delete anything from your answer. (I have no comment on the review issue, since I don't know what's going on.)

Comment: @psubsee2003: As I recall, edits made within 5 minutes of posting don't appear in the edit history.

Comment: @KeithThompson correct, but I doubt there is any grace period issues here as the only time that would apply is if he edited his own post within 5 minutes, which wouldn't have been a suggested edit either.

Comment: @BradLarson: (and others) yes, exactly. But why did this pop in my inbox? (or what I thought was my inbox?)

Comment: @gnometorule it was an edit proposed by someone else to your post and was offering you a chance to approve or reject it.  But 3 other users rejected it before you could review it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Probably all but the one pointed out by someone else were within 5 minutes in the process of answer cleanup.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Is this a new feature? I thought they go into the general review queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be some confusion here on just how edits work as what you are describing is not possible,

1. Edits you make to your own post (while logged in of course) never require review.  As the original author you will retain full edit rights to that post as long as it is there.  This means your edits will never be rejected
2. With the privilege mentioned above, you also are granted full review privileges to edits suggested to your own post.

So no one rejected any of your edits.  The inbox notification you mentioned above was notifying you that someone [proposed an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4502805) to your post and was offering you the opportunity to review it and either approve or reject the proposed edit.  However, by the time you got to that page, 3 people had already review it and rejected it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and sorry for the confusion. As mentioned elsewhere, is this new? My understanding had been that only edits by users with insufficient reputation need approval, and that those go into a general review queue, not to the author.

Comment: @gnometorule they do go to a general review queue, but as the author you are notified of the edit and given the ability to review it yourself from the review queue

Comment: Yes, I read the very helpful link you added as a comment above. Tyvm.